# How to make a horizontal scrolling area for left-floating element?

Tags: html, css

I want this outer `<div>` to scroll in the x-axis only, but it's not working.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 98%;
  height: 320px;
  padding-left:1%;
  padding-right:1%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  background-color: #fff;
  float:left;
  position:absolute;
}

.internal {
  width:250px;
  height:320px;
  display: inline;
  background-color: wheat;
  float:left;
  position:static;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="internal">item 1</div>
    <div class="internal">item 2</div>
    <div class="internal">item 3</div>
    <div class="internal">item 4</div>
    <div class="internal">item 5</div>
    <div class="internal">item 6</div>
    <div class="internal">item 7</div>
</div>
```

On my screen, it renders as:

[image: screenshot showing undesired behavior]

What is wrong?

Comment: what do u mean by "horizontal scrolling area?"

Comment: @Alex like this demo: http://codepen.io/benfrain/pen/vGetI
Sorry, my english not good!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your code is a bit of a mess.  You have a bunch of overriding rules in the same selector.

You need to wrap your items in an inner container thats set to a larger size than the wrapper.  Here is your code, cleaned up:

http://jsfiddle.net/aLysdueo/

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="internal">item 1</div>
        <div class="internal">item 2</div>
        <div class="internal">item 3</div>
        <div class="internal">item 4</div>
        <div class="internal">item 5</div>
        <div class="internal">item 6</div>
        <div class="internal">item 7</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 98%;
    height: 320px;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
.container {
    width: 1500px;
    height: 320px;
}

.internal {
    float:left;
    width:250px;
    height:320px;
    background-color: wheat;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Its woking.